# What repositories to add for apt-get to find python-opencv

Tags: apt, opencv

I've been trying to install the packages necessary to play with shape recognition with a camera. Virtually all sites recommend using opencv, and tell, like [here](https://www.open-electronics.org/computer-vision-with-raspberry-pi-and-the-camera-pi-module/), [here](https://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/) and [here](http://trevorappleton.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/python-getting-started-with-opencv.html), to install it with

```
apt‐get install python‐opencv
```

Sometimes with `sudo`. They drop the command without a second thought, like it should have no reason to fail. The problem is that my `apt-get` does not find the packages.

```
$ > sudo apt-get install python‐opencv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python‐opencv
```

I guess I'm missing one or more lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` but could not find which ones by STFW. Here's the contents of the file right now, which came default with the install of raspbian:

```
> cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
# deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

I've tried to uncomment the `deb-src` line and add the following line I found somewhere, to no avail:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe
```

Running `sudo apt-get update` works for some time, ignores (lines starting with `Ign`?) many packages, gets a handful of packages, then gives the following error, which I'm not sure is critical:

```
W: The repository 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-all/Packages.gz  Redirection loop encountered
E: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 141.30.62.22 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have an 8GB not full SDCard that I formatted by following the instructions under `Download NOOBS files then drag and drop` [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/software-guide/quickstart/).

What am I missing?

Comment: try to follow this link:
https://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/
bye.

Comment: Your sources list looks OK.  Have you recently tried `sudo apt-get update`? If not, try that, then run the install again. Perhaps your package lists are out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of formatting the SDCard then copying the NOOBS files to it, I flashed it with an image, as described under `Download and image Raspbian directly`
 [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/software-guide/quickstart/). Then everything went smoothly.